# JSF Converter with Dynamic parameter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, converters

Is it possible to have a JSF converter with dynamic parameters?
I understand you can sort of pass parameters using the `<f:attribute name='myName' value='yourValue' />` and then access them on your getAsObject method using the getAttributesbutes.get('myName'). But I'd like to do the conversion based on the user's selection on a select menu and I know the value of the f:attribute element can not be set dynamically. I've been researching for a bit now and haven't found anything. Any pointers, ideas, or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? Sounds like putting businesslogic in the view layer.

Comment: It's how the system is setup atm. But if there are no options available, and assuming I assign the user's choice on the dropdown to a bean variable, how would I access this bean variable from the converter?

Comment: Whilst the duplicate answers it for a custom validator, the principle is exactly the same for a custom converter.

Comment: Thank you @BalusC, I believe the solution on your site should work, but I have the following problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48178010/binding-of-composite-attribute